# Selenium find_elements function return Object (Selenium 4)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.8

thank you for helping me.

I usually used Selenium 2,3 but today I try using Selenium 4 to use new features `Relative Locators` . I do a simple find expression but it always return weird Object like below

```
> print(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a"))
{'ELEMENT': '0.4746792741017858-194'}
```

Or I find multiples

```
> print(driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a"))
[{'ELEMENT': '0.4746792741017858-178'}, {'ELEMENT': '0.4746792741017858-179'}]
```

I expect it return WebDriver Object, but it doesn't
Here is image of code and print statements.
[image]
Does anyone know this thing?
Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you have in print command?

Comment: @cruisepandey
Exactly the same above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the asnwer for this issue.
This is my set up:

```
chromedriver: 71.0.3578.80
chromebrowser: 99.0
selenium: 4
```

Basically, I'm using Selenium 4 which only support for above chromedriver: > 92. But my chromedriver v.71 -> outdate.

So that's why it's not compatible. So please check your chromedriver version if you choose selenium 4.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code

```
print(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a"))
```

output on **selenium 3:**

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="251a91865546a6c66596a267e20688d1", element="a36e87f3-bf6a-475c-82e4-07e4febe0dc5")>
```

output on **selenium 4:**

```
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (cbd87e312a3869b75a472d747371fd57)] -> tag name: a]
```

and your expectation :

> I expect it return WebDriver Object, but it doesn't

Note that `driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")` will always return a web element. It won't return a webdriver object.

on a web element you can perform `.text`, `.send_keys`, `.click` etc method

**Update:**

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'q').send_keys('etc')
```

Comment: Sorry, I was confused between those two concepts (WebElement and WebDriver).
I exactly mean I expect it returns WebElement.
I edit my question, please check it if you have time.

Comment: I'm using EC2 for crawling/selenium stuffs. It ran normally in other EC2 devices and my local machine. But not in this device.

Comment: those two statement that you've in your code would return a web element, and since it's a google search page, I know it'd target the search input box which is present in the middle of the screen. You should not be printing a web element. You should be using `.send_keys` to send some text into the search bar.

Comment: `driver.find_element(By.Name, "q").send_keys('DFX Nguyễn')` like this

Comment: It doesn't work, it got error. `'dict' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
`

Comment: basaclly it should be returned as a web element but a dict like this `{'ELEMENT': '0.4746792741017858-194'}`

Comment: I am not here for any argumentative stuff, you might have used `find_elements` instead of `find_element`

Comment: I tried to use find_elements but it doesn't work as well, it return 
`Selenium 3:  [{'ELEMENT': '0.6943835161376264-1'}]` when I print it out.
I dont mean to argue, I'm so sorry about that.

Comment: Check the update above, that is working in my local setup.

Comment: thank you for your kind help, I found the problem. Thank you.